# subprocess.Popen: sequence vs a single string

Tags: python, process

In the documentaiton for [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) I read:

> class subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, ...)
>
> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single
>   string. [...] Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args
>   as a sequence.

Why is it recommended to use a sequence for args? What are the cases when I must use a single  string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix a single string argument to `Popen` only works if you're not passing arguments to the program. Otherwise you would need `shell=True`. That's because the string is interpreted as the name of the program to execute.

Using a sequence also tends to be more secure. If you get program arguments from the user, you must fully sanitize them before appending to the command string. Otherwise the user will be able to pass arbitrary commands for execution. Consider the following example:

```
>>> def ping(host):
...   cmd = "ping -c 1 {}".format(host)
...   Popen(cmd, shell=True)
... 
>>> ping(input())
8.8.8.8; cat /etc/passwd
```

Using a sequence for args helps to avoid such vulnerabilities.